# What does the `return +self` do?

Tags: python, pep

In [PEP 3141](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3141/) I noticed a peculiar fragment which I don't fully understand. In class `Real` functions `real()` and `conjugate()` return `+self`, like so:

```
@property
def real(self):
    return +self
```

Why is there a `+` in front of `self`? What does it do? Or is it just some kind of a typo..?

Comment: Unary `+` operator: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations  I think it's just asserting that `self` is numeric.

Comment: It's a unary plus, it invokes [`__pos__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__pos__).

Comment: My guess would be that that's some sneaky way to convert the `Real` `self` to a `float` or other "normal" numeric type.

Comment: So since `__pos__()` implemented in super-class raises `NotImplementedError`, is it a way to force overriding it in the sub-class just to make `real()` and `conjugate()` usable?